# How do I limit (or truncate) text file by number of lines?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, text-files, unix-head

I would like to use a terminal/shell to truncate or otherwise limit a text file to a certain number of lines.

I have a whole directory of text files, for each of which only the first ~50k lines are useful.

How do I delete all lines over 50000?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

### In-place truncation

To truncate the file in-place with sed, you can do the following:

```
sed -i '50001,$ d' filename
```

- `-i` means in place.
- `d` means delete.
- `50001,$` means the lines from 50001 to the end.

You can make a backup of the file by adding an extension argument to `-i`, for example, `.backup` or `.bak`:

```
sed -i.backup '50001,$ d' filename
```

In [OS-X or FreeBSD](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html#uh-62h) you must provide an argument to `-i` - so to do this while avoiding making a backup:

```
sed -i '' '50001,$ d' filename
```

The long argument name version is as follows, with and without the backup argument:

```
sed --in-place '50001,$ d' filename
sed --in-place=.backup '50001,$ d' filename
```

### New File

To create a new truncated file, just redirect from head to the new file:

```
head -n50000 oldfilename > newfilename
```

- `-n50000` means the number of lines, head otherwise defaults to 10.
- `>` means to redirect into, overwriting anything else that might be there.
- Substitute `>>` for `>` if you mean to append into the new file.

It is unfortunate that you cannot redirect into the same file, which is why sed is recommended for in-place truncation.

### No sed? Try Python!

This is a bit more typing than sed. Sed is short for "Stream Editor" after all, and that's another reason to use it, it's what the tool is suited for.

This was tested on Linux and Windows with Python 3:

```
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice

def truncate(filename, lines):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        blackhole = deque((),0).extend
        file_iterator = iter(f.readline, '')
        blackhole(islice(file_iterator, lines))
        f.truncate(f.tell())
```

To explain the Python:

The blackhole works like `/dev/null`. It's a bound `extend` method on a `deque` with `maxlen=0`, which is the fastest way to exhaust an iterator in Python (that I'm aware of).

We can't simply loop over the file object because the `tell` method would be blocked, so we need the `iter(f.readline, '')` trick.

This function demonstrates the context manager, but it's a bit superfluous since Python would close the file on exiting the function. Usage is simply:

```
>>> truncate('filename', 50000)
```

Comment: how about just retaining the last 50000 lines?

Comment: How could I do this truncation recursively in a directory

Comment: @danielrvt `find` with `-exec sed...` should allow you to do that: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dexec-1

Answer (score 13):

Very easy indeed using sed:

```
sed -n '1,50000 p' filename
```

This will only print lines 1 to 50000 in the file 'filename'.

Comment: I wanted ellipsis after the last line iif the text was trucate. I got `yes | head -n 30 | nl | sed -ne '1,20 p' -e '21 i...'`

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer with 80 votes. SO will always surprise me.