# In Matlab: How to delete a line range from line xxx to the end of file in multiple data files

Tags: matlab, file, text-files, delete-row, temp

I have multiple data files that, sometimes, I want to delete unnecessary extra data lines in them, say from line 8000 to the last line. I want to do that for all the data files, which are contained in .txt files. I used to do it manually, but it's a tedious job to do that frequently.
I have combined and modified some codes that found I online, but I have two issues with it:

1. I don't know how to set the range, so that the code will delete all lines after line 8000. until the end of data Therefore I have assumed that the number of lines to be deletes is some large number (1000). But that's not a good solution, since the total number of lines in the data file might be more than 9000.
2. The second thing is that I cannot copy or move the created temp file, which contains the new data without the extra lines to replace the original file :( I found out the the universally unique identifier (UUID) in the temp folder is not the same as the one in the "`outfile`" for instance the UUID code for `outfile` in Matlab is `tp58460076_aaad_4621_b2ac_c7036febc3f0` and in temp folder it is `tp30ade3f8_3abc_4e00_a2ef_26d67c5f836e` I have used both `copyfile` and `movefile` in Matlab

If someone have an alternative solution or knows what's going wrong with this code, please help!

```
close all
clear
clc
% Specify the folder where the files live.
myFolder = 'C:\Users\Emma\Data';
% Check to make sure that folder actually exists.  Warn user if it doesn't.
if ~isdir(myFolder)
  errorMessage = sprintf('Error: The following folder does not exist:\n%s', myFolder);
  uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
  return;
end
% Get a list of all files in the folder with the desired file name pattern.
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.txt'); % Change to whatever pattern you need.
theFiles = dir(filePattern);

for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
  baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
  fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
%*****************************
first_line_to_delete = 8003;
num_lines_to_delete = 1000;
infilename = fullFileName;
[pathstr, file, ext] = fileparts(infilename);
backfile = fullfile(pathstr, [file '.bak']);
if strcmp(infilename, backfile)
  error('I refuse to edit a backup file! Nothing has been changed.');
end

outfile = tempname;   %a temporary file in TMP directory
fin = fopen(infilename, 'r');
if fin < 0; error('Input file does not exist'); end 
fout = fopen(tempname, 'w');
if fout < 0
  fclose(fin);
  error('Could not open temporary output file');
end

%read lines before the one to be deleted and write them to output
for K = 1 : first_line_to_delete - 1;
  inline = fgets(fin);
  if ~ischar(inline); break; end;  %end of file?
  fwrite(fout, inline);
end
for K = 1 : num_lines_to_delete;
  if ~ischar(inline); break; end   %in case EOF
  inline = fgets(fin);   %and do nothing with it
end
%copy all remaining input lines to output file
while ischar(inline)
  inline = fgets(fin);
  if ischar(inline)   %not if we hit EOF
    fwrite(fout, inline);
  end
end
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);

%we did the copying and have a file with the desired
%result. Now put it in the proper place
[status,message,messageId]  = copyfile(infilename, backfile, 'f'); %Emma mod
if ~status
  if strcmp(infilename, backfile)
    fprintf(2, 'Good thing your programmer is paranoid about people overriding\nsanity checks, because something went wrong and you nearly lost your file!\n');
  else
    delete(backfile);
  end
  error('Could not rename file to .bak, file left untouched');
else
  [status,message,messageId]  = copyfile(fullfile(outfile, [myFolder, infilename]), 'f');
  if ~status
    error( ['Could not rename temp file to original name, original moved to ', backfile]);
  end
end
%**************************
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017994/how-do-i-limit-or-truncate-text-file-by-number-of-lines. Otherwise, just delete the `for K = ...` loop and the subsequent `while ischar...` loop entirely.

Comment: @beaker Thank you very much! A shell script of one line replaced this lengthy Matlab code :) Luckily I have access to some terminal!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is the following command:

```
sed -i '8003,$ d' *.txt
```